# Different partial view per module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have different namespaced controllers that share the same layout:

```
# /app/controllers/admin/dashboard.rb
class Admins::DashboardController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

---

```
# /app/controllers/clients/dashboard.rb
class Clients::DashboardController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

This is my directory structure:

```
App
|_ Controllers
|  |_ Admins
|  |  |_ dashboard_controller.rb
|  |_ Clients
|     |_ dashboard_controller.rb
|
|_ Views
   |_ Admins
   |  |_ Dashboard
   |     |_ index.html.erb
   |
   |     |_ show.html.erb
   |_ Clients
   |  |_ Dashboard
   |     |_ index.html.erb
   |     |_ show.html.erb
   |_ layouts
      |_ admin.html.erb
      |_ _sidebar.html.erb
```

I'd like to determine whether the layout is displayed by `Admins` or `Clients` so i can show the correct sidebar, Something like:

```
<% if admins? %>
  ...
<% elsif clients? %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Also is this even the best way to approach this or there's a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template inheritance to achieve this. Simply `render 'sidebar'` in the layout you want to reuse and have your _sidebar templates defined in:

```
app/views/admins/dashboard/_sidebar.html.erb  # for Admins::DashboardController
app/views/clients/dashboard/_sidebar.html.erb # for Clients::DashboardController
app/views/application/_sidebar.html.erb         # fallback sidebar
```

Rails will automagically chose the right sidebar for you thanks to template inheritance.

If you want to use the corresponding sidebar in other Admin/Client controllers as well, you could also have a BaseController for each of them, like so:

```
class Admins::BaseController < ApplicationController

end

class Admins::DashboardController < Admins::BaseController
  ...
end
```

Now have a `_sidebar.html.erb` template in `app/views/admins/base/` and make sure that every Controller in Admins namespace inherits from Admins::BaseController.

You will see that this opens up a very nice way to structure common functionality / callbacks etc. for all your namespaced controllers as well. Also, it lets you overwrite the sidebar partial whenever you require it just by placing a `_sidebar.html.erb` file in any more specific view path, e.g. `app/views/admins/myspecificsidebars/_sidebar.html.erb`.

Comment: As always, there's a good Railscast on this topic (it helped me structure my templates A LOT!): http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance

Comment: Thanks but that requires me to put the sidebar partial in every controller's folder instead of just in the root of Admins folder or Clients folder.

Comment: Not necessarily - could you please check for the paths in which rails tries to find the template? Might well be that `app/views/admins/` or `app/views/admins/application` is among them.

Comment: I tried it, It searches for `_sidebar` in `app/views/admins/dashboard`, not `app/views/admins`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14077/discussion-between-ryan-and-blackbird07)

Answer (score 0):

Use the layout method of `ApplicationController`.

```
layout :user_layout

def user_layout
  #your layout logic here, return the name of the layout
end
```

Comment: I'm not trying to show a different layout, I just want to show custom content (sidebar) depending on the parent module

Comment: you should use a different layout for each dashboard

Comment: That's very repetitive, at least for my case.